# Angular2 @Input and lifecycle hook

Tags: angular, input

I have following component:

```
export class AddressListComponent implements AfterViewInit{   
  @Input() districts: District[] = [];

  constructor() { }

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    console.log(this.districts);   } }
```

So it console logs districts as empty array, but I send it as input non-empty array and it displays well this html:

```
<a *ngFor = "let district of districts; let i = index"  class="list-group-item clearfix" >
        WORKS
 </a>
```

So my question is next: when in the lifecycle hook am I able to console log data from `districts` array? Because I need to change it before displaying on html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should work fine. I think your parent component it's being populating the variable `districts` after `AddressListComponent` it's loaded. Check to load your child component before you set the variable `districts`, or use `ngOnChanges` instead of `ngAfterViewInit` (ngOnChangess hooks to every change , and not only to the init of the component)

Comment: ngOnChanges worked! I found what was the problem. THe problem was that ngOnInit is called BEFORE districts is loaded from server side

Comment: Maybe you can add a callback too, so you can set a loading in the app, and load all the components after that. But yes, it's a pain some of the lifecycle hooks

Answer (score 4):

> when in the lifecycle hook am I able to console log data from
>   districts array

All inputs are available in the `ngOnInit` lifecycle hook for the first time the component is initialized. For the consequent updates use `ngOnChanges`. Or you can use `ngOnChanges` only since it's also called when the component is initialized.

You can see it from the order of operations mentioned in the [Everything you need to know about change detection in Angular](https://hackernoon.com/everything-you-need-to-know-about-change-detection-in-angular-8006c51d206f):

1) updates input properties on a child component/directive instance
...
3) calls `OnChanges` lifecycle hook on a child component if bindings changed
4) calls `OnInit` and `ngDoCheck` on a child component (`OnInit` is called only during first check)

Comment: @mondayguy, try `ngOnChanges` but something is wrong with your setup because inputs should be avalaible in `ngOnInit`. Maybe add some more information to your question details

Comment: @mondayguy Please reproduce it. You are doing something wrong or you didn't provide enough information

Comment: ngOnChanges worked! I found what was the problem. THe problem was that ngOnInit is called BEFORE districts is loaded from server side

Comment: @mondayguy, okay, maybe consider  accepting my answer then

Comment: sorry, I just +1 your answer, Sebastian gave correct answer too. Thank you on more time

Comment: @mondayguy, sure, no problem